# Type or namespace name 'VisualStudio' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft'

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, namespaces

I can see from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2012/ms244252(v=vs.110)), that the namespace `Visual Studio` should exist within namespace `Microsoft`, yet I get that error and none of my tests are working!

> The type or namespace name 'VisualStudio' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

I am using Visual Studio 2012 with Windows 8.1 (all updated).

Comment: Check for target .net fw.  I.e .Net 4 CLIENT framework vs .Net 4.0 FULL framework. Also make sure the correct version of unit test dll exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found out what the issue was. I had all the solution files in a different place than the usual default.

I had them in a Dropbox folder hoping that I can work on the solution from multiple computers, but apparently that was the cause of the issue.

Moving the whole solution to the default My Documents/VS 2012/Projects/ fixed the problem for me!

In short, if you want things to work smoothly, have the solution files in the usual place, unless you're an advanced user and know what you're doing (I'm not).

Comment: I did move the project into its place Documents/VS 2010/Projects/ but still i am getting this error
Error 1 The type or namespace name 'VisualStudio' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: Are you using VS2010? If not, it needs to go into the right folder

Comment: I'm using vs 2010 and i placed it in documents/vs2010/projects/ still it gives me the error

Comment: You don't have your documents folder shared via networks ...etc do you?

Comment: No i dont have it shared i guess its some dll problem

Comment: "...hoping that I can work on the solution from multiple computers..."  that's what source control is for.

Answer (score 29):

I got this error when trying to build a project in TFS. These steps fixed it:

- remove reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework
- add nuget **MSTest.TestFramework**
- add nuget **MSTest.TestAdapter** (optional but needed to run tests inside Visual Studio)

---

The above steps caused this element to be removed from my .csproj file:

```
<Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework" />
```

And these two were added instead:

```
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.2.1.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
      <HintPath>..\packages\MSTest.TestFramework.2.1.1\lib\net45\Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions.dll</HintPath>
    </Reference>
```

Comment: Copy Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll somewhere into the root folder of project. When later you will be building test project in console or otherwise, copy it back to debug\bin. 
If a project has no reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework I have experienced problems launching tests from Visual Studio UI -> glitches.

Comment: I also updated the whole project to SDK style type. Then I removed the references and replaced them with the PackageReferences (it's of course much easier to add or remove references, in SDK style projects, because you don't have to unload and load them to edit the XML). Then it worked for me (in TFS).

Answer (score 9):

If you're using VS 2017, simply don't put the original project and the test project in the same folder. This will solve the conflict.

Answer (score 6):

The namespace Microsoft.VisualStudio... is defined in assemblies which are not part of the standard Installation of Visual Studio. It is available only if you installed the Visual Studio SDK.

The MSDN Reference to the SDK and included namespaces can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb166217%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

After installing the SDK add a reference to the required assemblies to your project as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wkze6zky.aspx).

EDIT: Please also check your Visual Studio Version. In the MSDN Link you have posted it says:

> You can customize some aspects of **Visual Studio Ultimate  or Visual Studio Premium** to extend existing features or to add new capabilities if you have special requirements. The API reference provides information about the classes to help you with your customization.

If you have one of these Versions, open your unit test project, right click on 'References' -> Choose 'Add Reference' -> Click on 'Assemblies' on the top left and search in the List for 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting' (Its either in the 'Framework' or in the 'Extensions' section which you can also choose on the left). You do not need to know the actual location of the dll.

Comment: Thanks Tobias, I downloaded and installed the VisualStudio SDK, but how do I reference it if I don't know where the .dll sits? I am doing a search on `Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting` but not getting anything. Also, notice that your MSDN Reference link does not include the Assembly I'm after .. has it all changed or something?

Comment: Hmm... I've looked a little further into this and obviously I've overlooked something. Can you please specify which version of Visual Studio 2012 you are using (Professional, Premium, Ultimate, Express)? It seems that the assemblies you are refering to are only available in Ulitmate and Premium Version.

Comment: I am using VS 2012 Professional. Are you saying I can't use that particular library of UnitTesting because I do not have VS 2012 Ultimate or Premium? :(

Comment: sorry Tobias, that wasn't it. :)

Comment: download link is forbidden

Answer (score 2):

For VS 2017, I had to change the Target Framework in Properties

Comment: I'm also using VS 2017, and all of my target frameworks are set to ".NET Framework 4.6.2", but I'm still getting this error, and can't find the dlls I need anywhere.

Comment: Interestingly, the MSDN documentation for this assembly _stops_ completely at Visual Studio 2013.  It doesn't say it's no longer supported, but they make a note that it's including the documentation from an older version.  Still looking into this further...

Comment: My problem is that the code was generated via SpecFlow, so I don't know how do resolve this quickly (IE, without rewriting large portions of SpecFlow).

Comment: The answer doesn't provide any specific setting what to change the target "to", nor why. Hence, it doesn't seem to work for me or Thought.

Comment: Changed TO what?

Answer (score 1):

I got this error after installing the NuGet `Microsoft.JavaScript.UnitTest`. After uninstall it worked.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.JavaScript.UnitTest/

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had an invalid private package source. Because of  this, I could not install any package at all (of course). Removing the invalid package source also allowed Visual Studio to install the packages correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest avoid using the "Add reference", it took me some time but I came across this NuGet that has everything that is needed for CodedUITests. 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/CodedUIDependencies/1.0.0

Answer (score 0):

Copy Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework.dll somewhere into the root folder of project. When later you will be building test project in console or otherwise, copy it back to debug\bin. 
If a project has no reference to Microsoft.VisualStudio.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework I have experienced problems launching tests from Visual Studio UI -> glitches.