# The type or namespace name 'VisualStudio' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, vs-unit-testing-framework

Getting the error

> The type or namespace name 'VisualStudio' does not exist in the
>   namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

on a project using MS Test 2 Framework.  I read the link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20259076/type-or-namespace-name-visualstudio-does-not-exist-in-the-namespace-microsoft) but it didn't help.

I believe I have the required references and object browser seems to find them:
References
[image: References]
Object Browser:
[image: Object Browser]

Nevertheless I'm getting tons of errors in my unit test project, starting with the one above.

How can I resolve this so the build can find the references it needs?

Comment: Clean and Build (rebuild)? delete bin and obj? restore/reinstall NuGet packages?

Comment: been there, done that. no joy

Comment: MSTest v2 was released in the summer of 2016, that makes VS2012 a pretty old dog.  I suspect there is a warning barely visible among the slew of errors that complains about the .NET target version.

Comment: That was a good tip!  Found this: Warning 1 The primary reference "Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestPlatform.TestFramework.Extensions" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Runtime, Version=4.0.10.0, The real problem I suspect

Comment: Yup, that is the real problem.

Answer (score 1):

In my case (vs2017 + TFS Builds), I ended up removing the MSTest v2 packages and installed the MSTest v1 package because our build servers don't support v2 yet. My solution would build locally but fail on our build server.

- Went into Manage NuGet Packages
- Uninstalled MSTest.TestAdapter & MSTest.TestFramework
- Installed VS.QualityTools.UnitTestFramework

Rebuild & Run tests to make sure and then check-in.

Answer (score 0):

The key for me was to add `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime` as a reference.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!